# ASP.NET partial page update with GET parameters

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a ASP text box which is acting as a search box. I have set AutoPostBack="True" and a server side ontextchanged event.  The text box is in an update panel to avoid a full page postback.  Currently the server event is fired when the text changes, without the page reloading.

For the sake of navigation and bookmarking, I want the URL to change to reflect the search string. e.g. "...MyPage.aspx?s=searchstring"

However, If I put something like this in the server event:

```
protected void txtMyBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/MyPage.aspx?s="+txtMyBox.Text);
}
```

The whole page reloads, whereas I only want a small area to be updated. Can I avoid this full reload when the URL is changed?

Comment: Why are you doing a post back on text box change? what is the functionality you are trying to access? there is a high probability that you can do the same functionality using Ajax with out a full page post back.

Comment: Sorry forgot to say that the text box is in an update panel. So I think that causes it to do an async postback using AJAX.  My question is, does changing the URL always cause a full page reload?